# Shelf stable caramels

Tags: storage-method

How can I make caramels at home that are shelf stable?

Comment: Most caramels (as in sweets) and some caramel sauces etc. are shelf-stable because of the very high sugar content/low water content.  I suggest you post the recipe you're starting from

Comment: Welcome to the site @laura, unfortunately your question isn't clear. Are you asking  about a sauce, or candies?

Comment: @laura, I edited your comment. I think this is what you are intending to ask.  If not, please clarify.  As the comment above suggests, adding a recipe might be helpful.

Comment: @moscafj Your edit makes this question read almost like a recipe request now -- however, I also think that without the recipe, it's going to be extremely difficult to suggest changes that can keep the caramels from spoiling too quickly.

Comment: @Erica I respectfully disagree.  There are many questions on this site regarding shelf stability, and a recipe is not required to answer this question.  However, the recipe used by Laura would be helpful in providing advice.

Answer (score 1):

My research confirms the first comment by @Chris H; that is, homemade caramels are shelf stable.  From a safety concern there is no problem.  However, some home candy makers describe a graininess that occurs over time, making the candy less pleasurable. Some folks have experimented with different types of sugars to attempt to combat this effect. Moisture absorption over time is another problem impacting quality.  Suggestions are to wrap individually, then place in an air tight container. There is actually quite a bit of discussion about caramels on the internets, if you want to compare your recipe to what others have tried.